# Django - {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I'm new to Django and I'm still trying to get to grips with its features. I've created very simple project with **Django 1.4.2** which has index page with simple form where you enter something and results page where your input is displayed after submission (the code is below).

After submission, I get error 403 and the following message:

> A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not
>   provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using
>   RequestContext.   warnings.warn("A {% csrf_token %} was used in a
>   template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually
>   caused by not using RequestContext.")

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Index page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">Welcome to index page</div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Enter your name</p>
        <form action="/result/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="answer">
            <input type="submit" value="Send!">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**result.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Result page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">Here is the result</div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Your name is: {{ answer }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')

def result(request):
    p = request.POST['answer']
    return render_to_response('result.html', {'answer': p}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I've looked into documentation and various examples on the Internet, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. If I disable **django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware** in **settings.py**, I get exactly what I want, but that's not the answer I'm looking for.

I appreciate help from more experienced Django ninjas :-)

Comment: Are you trying with django runserver ?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing with "manage.py runserver". Is there some kind of limitation?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your `index.html` is rendered without `RequestContext`. Try this:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I also recomend you to use more convenient shortcut [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render('index.html')
```

From docs:

> render() is the same as a call to render_to_response() with a
>   context_instance argument that forces the use of a RequestContext.

**EDIT**:

Thanks [@nerdwaller](https://stackoverflow.com/u/1584762/) for mentioning, newer versions now needs:

```
render(request, 'index.html', {params});
```

Comment: Oh dear, silly me. This was the solution all along. I thought I needed to define RequestContext only in the view where the POST data was actually being sent. Thx @goliney!

Comment: Thanks for the pro tip! My problem is solved and your answer is accepted :-)

Comment: Recent versions of django require:  `render(request, 'index.html', {params});` for anyone looking. [See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error using Django 2.1, turned out that it was caused by make an ajax request in the template that was called by another ajax request.  So, the solution was to add 'request=request' to my render function:

```
args = {'someargs': somevalues}
html = render_to_string(
        'my_template.html', context=args, request=request)
return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: I was looking for an answer, why the combination of django + class based view + form + async + render_to_string + csrf is not working. `request=request` was the solution for missing csrf token.