# CSRF Error: Token Missing in Template ( Python 3 )

Tags: javascript, django, html, python-3.x, csrf

The error I've been getting is this :

Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure :

- Your browser is accepting cookies.
- The view function passes a request to the template's render method.
- In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
- If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.

```html
    
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Log In</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 
    <div class="container" style="max-width:400px">

          <form method="post" class="form-signin">{% csrf_token %}
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Log in</h2>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" autofocus>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
          </form>
      <p>{{error}}</p>
        </div> <!-- /container -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried to put in `context` but that didn't make the error go away either :

```
# views.py
def login(request):
    if request.user.username and request.user.profile.is_chat_user:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    context = {'error':''}  

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username','') #retunr '' if no username
        password = request.POST.get('password','')

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            cu = request.user.profile
            cu.is_chat_user = True
            cu.last_accessed = utcnow()
            cu.save()



            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            #context['error'] = ' wrong credentials try again'
            return render('index.html')
            #return render(request,'djangoChat/login.html',context)


    #context.update(csrf(request))      
    return render('index.html')
    #return render(request,'djangoChat/login.html',context)
```

The `views.py` file has this : `from django.views.decorators.csrf     import csrf_exempt`

I saw a few similar cases but none of them explained the cause and how to avoid this error.

Comment: Is there any chance you support http and https?

Comment: Is the URL that you're trying to access excluded from generating CSRF tokens ?

Comment: is your template rendered [with context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048228/django-csrf-token-was-used-in-a-template-but-the-context-did-not-provid) ?

Comment: what is the default value for the form's `action` attribute? It is missing

Comment: It's a local Django chat app I downloaded but can't get to work, perhaps because it was originally coded in Python2.7 and I'm trying to make it work in Python3. I changed all the print statements to print(). However I don't understand anything about this csrf error.

Comment: see the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/)

Comment: is django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware in your  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting ?

Comment: After loading page, can you inspect the html-source to confirm the csrf hidden input field is correctly populated or not?