# CSRF errors when trying to add simple product to shopping cart

Tags: python, django, csrf

I am getting the error

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

when trying to use 'add to cart' with a simple cart application I wrote.

The code in my template:

```
<form action="{% url "cart:cart_add" instance.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ cart_product_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="add to cart">
</form>
```

And my views from views.py:

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

def cart_detail(request):
    template = loader.get_template('/webapps/my_webapp/furniture_site/cart/templates/cart/detail.html')
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'], 'update': True})
    context={'cart': cart}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Everything seems fine as far as I can see, what am I missing?

My middleware config:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
]
```

Alternative view that still does not work:

```
def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'], 'update': True})
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

edit: This does not seem to be a duplicate of the marked question, as the answer to that question was to use render to return request, which I am doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - {% csrf\_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048228/django-csrf-token-was-used-in-a-template-but-the-context-did-not-provid)

Comment: @atn, context does provide the value though

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache and reload page. 
If not solve then give exact error traceback.

Edited:
`from django.template import RequestContext`

`return render_to_response('results.html', {'results' : results}, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )`

Try this

Comment: Clearing cache and reloading did not help, even used a different browser. How do I give specific error traceback, nothing is put out to page

Comment: Can you add your settings.py middleware config

Comment: Added to question

Comment: I changed view per your answer and added to question, still get same error

Comment: @waqasgard I did just now and that solved my problem! But surely a shopping cart should not be csrf_exempt!

Comment: @JakeRankin If you're a frontend developer you'd definitely know what CSRF tokens are for and how you've to pass that with your requests for Django to verify your browser. If not please ask your Frontend developer to take care of this. This is not Django's problem.

Comment: @waqasgard Not a frontend developer but I have a background in security, I understand what CSRF tokens are and how they are used. This is django throwing the error, so how is it not a django problem?

Comment: What I meant by that is your frontend is not handling the tokens correctly as in it's not passing the tokens correctly to Django and hence Django throws this error.

Comment: @waqasgard not as of yet, everything I can see indicates I am sending the csrf_token correctly from the form and it is being received by the view